# Git submodule branch based on condition

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to change my git model to have a `master` and `develop` branch. I have a submodule that also has a `master` and `develop` branch. My `.gitmodules` looks something like this currently

```
[submodule "foo"]
    path = foo
    url = git.bar.com/foo.git
```

When I need to pull in changes from the `develop` branch of the submodule in the `develop` branch of my main repository, I do something like

```
cd foo
git checkout develop
git pull origin
cd ..
git commit
git push
```

Whereas, in the `master` branch, I can do `git submodule update --remote` to get the latest commit from the `master` branch of the submodule. I would like to be able to do the same for the `develop` branches.

Is there any way to conditionally set the branch in `.gitmodules`? I know am I can permanently set the branch with

```
[submodule "foo"]
    path = foo
    url = git.bar.com/foo.git
    branch = develop
```

But this will then move the problem to `master`

Comment: `.gitmodules` is per branch; e.g. your master branch can contain `branch = master` while develop has `branch = develop`.

Comment: @ensc `develop` branch merges into `master`, so they wouldn't need to constantly change back and forth

Answer (score 1):

In the branch `master` of the super project make it

```
[submodule "foo"]
    path = foo
    url = git.bar.com/foo.git
    branch = master
```

In the branch `develop` of the super:

```
[submodule "foo"]
    path = foo
    url = git.bar.com/foo.git
    branch = develop
```

Add `post-checkout` hook to the super project that switch branche on the
submodule:

```
#!/bin/sh

# post-checkout hook that switch branch on submodule

prev_HEAD="$1"
new_HEAD="$2"
new_branch="$3"

if [ "$new_branch" = 1 ]; then
   git submodule update
fi
```